# iOS Simulator not showing iPhone Frame

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I've read a few other posts on this, and tried the solutions but they don't work. I also tried CMD-1 to show it at full resolution, and still no frame. I also added a frame.png file to the contents->resources folder for iOS Simulator app and still nothing. To be clear, I'm trying to get the iPhone frame around my emulator

I'm building my iOS application with ionic. I'm using iOS Simulator 8.1 and Xcode 6.1.1

Would appreciate any help, giving a presentation tomorrow at school and hoping to have this thing polished. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Apple removed this in Xcode 5 (or around that time). You cannot get this feature any longer.

Comment: Thanks for the update....that's a bummer! Is it some sort of branding reasons?

Answer (score 0):

As @timgcarlson said, Apple removed this in Xcode 5 (or around that time). You cannot get this feature any longer. Bummer!

Comment: I think that this response is redundant here as @timgcarlson already answered ;)